# How to import backgrounds and images into pygame

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.7

So im making a game with pygame. I got most of the code done and the art is all done. But pygame gives an error when I try to load the sprites. The error says "Couldn't open person1.png, File [file location], line 8, in  char = pygame.image.load('person1.png')

This is for a game im making using pygame. I've tried to use the help from other people on other questions about the same problem. It's always come back to "Couldn't open person1.png".

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
debug = True # If set to True, The console will print out the X and Y cords

win = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720)) # Game runs at 720p
pygame.display.set_caption("[Name (I dont want to leak the name)] ALPHA")
char = pygame.image.load('person1.png') # Sprites
bg = pygame.image.load('stage1.png')
isClimbing = True


x = 50
y = 50

height = 69
width = 69

vel = 13
level = 0

isJump = False
jumpCount = 10



run = True

if y > 335 or y < 335: 
            y = 335



def next_stage(): # Used for going on to the next stage
    stage + 1
    level = 0


def redrawGameWindow(): # Redraws the Game Window
    global walkCount 

    win.blit(bg, (0,0)) 
    win.blit(char, (x, y)) #Replaces the Rectangle with the sprite
    pygame.display.update()

# MAIN GAME LOOP BELOW
```

Comment: maybe image is in different folder then you run code so use `/full/path/to/person1.png`

Comment: you could check in any image viewer if this file can be displayed - it can be broken.

Answer (score 1):

You must write `.convert()` or `.convert_alpha()` to let pygame read correctly the given image:

```py
img = pygame.image.load('my_image.png').convert_alpha()
```

note that convert_alpha() will convert too, but will care about image's alpha (opacity)

Comment: It's good practice to use `convert()` as it'll transform the pixel format to the format that's fastest for blitting, but it's actually not necessary and it'll work if you omit it.